# Selecting VPN for transparent site to site VLAN bridging

Tags: vlan, vpn, layer2

I want to connect our branch office to main office with VPN, but I have following constraints:

- branch office is behind dynamic IP and NAT
- main office has static Public IP available for this purpose
- clients on branch office should access internet directly, and only needed internal resources through VPN
- several subnets on main office need to be accessible to clients on branch office (through routing)
- two VLANs (where one is for VoIP) need to be bridged across offices completely transparently
- VPN device on branch office should be, as much as possible, maintenance free *"set and forget"*
- we prefer open source approach whenever possible
- expected bandwidth usage for this connection is not much (e.g. 10 Mbit or less)

Can this be done with OpenVPN?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the opinion-based part.  Now let me give you an opinion: bridging VLANs is a bad idea.  Avoid it.  Trying to both bridge and route over a single VPN tunnel is difficult at best.

Comment: What are your router models? This should probably be done on the router.

Comment: I have problem with VoIP VLAN which is not under my control. Basically phones are booted over LAN and only thing I can think of is to extend the whole VLAN providing voice. Everything else I could workaround by classic VPN. I have UniFi equipment in main office, but for this purpose I could also get Linux machine or dedicated router.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done with OpenVPN?

It can almost certainly be done with a combination of OpenVPN and the networking features in the Linux kernel.

Two openVPN instances one for each VLAN, bridged to the real networks with Linux bridging can connect the sites.

Keeping internet traffic local can be achived in a few ways. One way would be to use different default gateway IPs for the two sides but that would then mean either forgoing DHCP on one side of the VPN or doing some fancy stuff in the DHCP server to give machines the right default gateway IP.

Another possibility may be to use the same default gateway IP on both sides and then use ebtables to block traffic to/from the default gateways from crossing the VPN.